# Cannot \newif inside a conditional

Tags: conditionals

I want to create a conditional if it is not defined yet.
The following is my unsuccessful attempt.

```
%%% in file A
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifdraft\drafttrue
\def\OptionLoaded{}

%%% in file B
\ifx \OptionLoaded \undefined
  \newif\ifdraft\draftfalse
\fi

\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

Error `Incomplete \ifx` raises when I compile the sample code.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Once I comment out the initial `\newif\ifdraft\drafttrue` this complies for me without any problems.

Comment: @Andrew I also found that.  But that is exactly what I need: if file A defines `\ifdraft`, then file B do nothing; if file A doesn't define `\ifdraft`, then file B should define it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the LaTeX tests they take care to lift the true and false branches out of the tex primitive conditional:

```
%%% in file A
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifdraft\drafttrue
\def\OptionLoaded{}

%%% in file B
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{OptionLoaded}{\newif\ifdraft\draftfalse}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

Your version fails as when the conditional is defined the `\ifx` test is false
so in

```
\ifx \OptionLoaded \undefined
  \newif\ifdraft\draftfalse
\fi
```

Tex tries to skip past `\newif\ifdraft\draftfalse` without evaluating anything so `\newif` is just an inert token, however when skipping it does match `\if` tokens so sees `\ifdraft` and the `\fi` but it carries on skipping expecting another `\fi` to close the `\ifx`.

Comment: +1 Perhaps in the real use-case `\OptionLoaded` is needed but at least in the MWE it is redundant and, instead, you could use `\@ifundefined{ifdraft}{\newif\ifdraft\draftfalse}{}`.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle), when TeX reads `\newif\ifdraft\draftfalse`, it will ignore `\newif` and consider `\ifdraft` as the opening of a conditional.
Thus another workaround is to replace `\ifdraft` with `\csname ifdraft\endcsname`.

```
%%% in file A
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifdraft\drafttrue
\def\OptionLoaded{}

%%% in file B
\ifx \OptionLoaded \undefined
  \expandafter\newif\csname ifdraft\endcsname\draftfalse
\fi

\begin{document}
\ifdraft
  hello
\else
  world
\fi
\end{document}
```